# How to combine two tables and applying sum-function on columns

Tags: sql, ms-access

Dear Stackoverflow Community,

I generated two new tables to summarize data based on month, which work perfectly fine. Both tables have the same structur (see screenshot).

```
SELECT  Cluster,
    format(Posteingang,"mm.yyyy") AS Monat,
    COUNT(Posteingang_Aufwand) AS Posteingang_Anz,
    ROUND((SUM(Posteingang_Aufwand))/60, 2) AS Posteingang_Std
INTO DOKU_POSTEINGANG_MONAT
FROM DOKU_AUFWAND INNER JOIN DOKU_VORGANG_BGD 
ON DOKU_AUFWAND.Vorgang_BGD = DOKU_VORGANG_BGD.Vorgang_BGD
    WHERE Posteingang BETWEEN #01/01/2020# AND #12/31/2020#
    GROUP BY format(Posteingang,"mm.yyyy"), Cluster 

SELECT Cluster,
    format(Posteingang_Bestaetigung,"mm.yyyy") AS Monat,
    COUNT(Posteingang_Aufwand_Bestaetigung) AS Posteingang_Bestätigung_Anz,
    ROUND((SUM(Posteingang_Aufwand_Bestaetigung))/60, 2) AS Posteingang__Bestätigung_Std
INTO DOKU_POSTEINGANG_BESTÄTIGUNG_MONAT
FROM DOKU_AUFWAND INNER JOIN DOKU_VORGANG_BGD 
ON DOKU_AUFWAND.Vorgang_BGD = DOKU_VORGANG_BGD.Vorgang_BGD
    WHERE Posteingang_Bestaetigung BETWEEN #01/01/2020# AND #12/31/2020#
    GROUP BY format(Posteingang_Bestaetigung,"mm.yyyy"), Cluster
```

[Output of one table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TEPwm.png)

After that, I like **to have the outputs of those two table in another one summarized** (xxx_Anz, xxx_Std). The **data needs to be grouped by the four "Clusters" again.** The statement below gives sth. back, however, the **amount summarized is far to high.**

```
SELECT  a.Cluster,
    (SUM(a.Posteingang_Anz) + SUM(b.Posteingang_Bestätigung_Anz)) AS Total_Anz,
    (SUM(a.Posteingang_Std) + SUM(b.Posteingang__Bestätigung_Std)) AS Total_Std
FROM DOKU_POSTEINGANG_MONAT AS a INNER JOIN DOKU_POSTEINGANG_BESTÄTIGUNG_MONAT AS b ON a.Cluster = b.Cluster
GROUP BY a.Cluster
```

Gives back the same result.

```
SELECT  a.Cluster,
    (SUM(a.Posteingang_Anz) + SUM(b.Posteingang_Bestätigung_Anz)) AS Total_Anz,
    (SUM(a.Posteingang_Std) + SUM(b.Posteingang__Bestätigung_Std)) AS Total_Std
FROM (SELECT * FROM DOKU_POSTEINGANG_MONAT AS a 
    INNER JOIN DOKU_POSTEINGANG_BESTÄTIGUNG_MONAT AS b 
        ON a.Cluster = b.Cluster)
GROUP BY a.Cluster
```

Any idea what the issue could be?

Many thanks in advance.

Cheers Sina

Comment: Your title asks about an error, the question is about numbers?

Comment: Your INNER JOINs need to be on `Cluster` and `Monat`, otherwise you are summing way too many records.

Comment: "Far too high" is too vague. Please post expected and actual numbers, if you can...

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Why do you have two tables with same structure and not one table?

Answer (score 0):

I realised the issue. I used the UNION ALL function and it works. Many thanks for the replies on my question.

```
Select  Cluster, 
    SUM(Anzahl) AS Anzahl_Total,
    SUM(Stunden) AS Stunden_Total
INTO AUFWAND_TOTAL
 FROM  (SELECT a.Cluster, a.Anzahl, a.Stunden
 FROM DOKU_POSTEINGANG_MONAT AS a
    UNION ALL SELECT b.Cluster, b.Anzahl, b.Stunden
 FROM DOKU_POSTEINGANG_BESTÄTIGUNG_MONAT AS b) 
    GROUP BY Cluster
```